# Local SSL Cert not trusted in Chrome/Firefox but works in Safari/Brave

Tags: safari, google-chrome, keychain, firefox

I'm struggling to update the local SSL certs for Chrome and Firefox in Monterey 12.6.

Specifically, I updated my local development server's SSL certs and "Always Trust"ed them in the Keychain Access as [directed here](https://medium.com/@matayoshi.mariano/how-to-add-ssl-to-your-localhost-with-puma-37a66a649f29).

Locally it works in Safari and Brave (which had never seen the old SSL cert), but Chrome and Firefox are always giving SSL cert errors (Chrome: NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID). I've tried fully clearing the All Time browser history as well as incognito/private which other posts recommend, but it hasn't worked yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started over even after fully reinstalling Firefox (manually removing all plist, cache dir's, folders).

I needed to run `mkcert -install` which I'm not sure how it was lost previously but that was it.